# Prevent circular imports for related object

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have two django models in two files:

parent.py

```
from child import Child
from django.db import models

def Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def createChild(self):
        return Child()
```

child.py

```
from parent import Parent
from django.db import models

def Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

However, this would lead to circular imports - is there a better way to organize this to prevent this?

Comment: What if you put them in the same file to avoid the import loop? They're tightly coupled anyway.

Comment: I have about 6 of such objects, so it would become a gigantic file containing almost my entire package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explicitly covered [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). There is no need to import the model; use a string in the format "app_name.ModelName" as the foreign key target.

```
def Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("parent.Parent")
```

Note also, there is no need to reference Child explicitly from Parent, either. Presumably, when you create a child from parent, you want one that references the parent; so you would do `self.child_set.create()`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second comment regarding `self.child_set.create()`